# Postgresql - How to convert a string array to bigint array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, bigint

I have a stored procedure and i have to convert a string array in a bigint array in a way like this:

```
lst_id  bigint[];
SELECT ARRAY[_id] INTO lst_id FROM tablename WHERE ARRAY[codes] <@ $1;
```

*lst_id* is my bigint array, *_id* is a column of my *tablename* and *codes* are another column of the table. $1 is my string array.

Unfortunatly, this not work. It takes only the first word in the array string and not all the words.
Why? Can someone help me?
Thanks
Christian

Comment: Please add some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

It should works, maybe your WHERE clause?

> ```
> create table tbl(id int[]);
> create table tbl2 (id bigint[]);
> insert into tbl select array[1,2,3,4,5];
> insert into tbl select array[1,2,3,14,5];
> insert into tbl select array[1,2,3,4,5];
> ```

> ```
> DO $$ 
>    declare lst_id bigint[];
> BEGIN
>   select id into lst_id from tbl where id @> array[14];
>   insert into tbl2 (id) values (lst_id);
> END $$;
> ```

> ```
> select * from tbl2;
> ```
>
> ```
> | id           |
> | :----------- |
> | {1,2,3,14,5} |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7e367b7330cc03c67e34ae806c1cbfc9)*